# Faster database access by using Laravel's Eloquent or query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I'm a little confused because some say that it's faster for the database access to use Query Builder instead of Eloquent ORM. 
Is there a difference from the access speed point of view, or are there some arguments that specify a method is better than the other?
Or it's just a matter of what suits best your project.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually you won't notice much of an impact when working on local projects. It really depends on the size of your DB. Eloquent allows you to take advantage of Laravel's ActiveRecord implementation, which basically means that it's easier to update the model's timestamps and so forth.